# How to read custom types from datastore

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

I have a datastore table, which is like that

```
Name/ID  |  UserEmail  |  UserRole  |  UserPermissions 
------------------------------------------------------
```

The `UserRole` attribute in json is a `string`. However, in `Go` code, it's a type

```
type UserDetails struct {
    NameID string
    UserEmail string
    UserRole UserType
    UserPermissions string //json??
}

type UserType string

const (
    UnknownUserRole UserType = "UNKNOWN"
    SiteAdmin       UserType = "SITE_ADMIN"
    SiteHR UserType = "SITE_HR"
)

func (ut *UserType) String() string {
    return string(*ut)
}

func UserTypeFromString(userType string) UserType {
    switch userType {
    case "SITE_ADMIN":
        return SiteAdmin
    case "SITE_HR":
        return SiteHR
    default:
        return UnknownRole
    }
}
```

Now, I have to read *all* users for given `org`. I am using this code to do so

```
func (c DataStoreClient) GetUserDetailsByOrg(ctx context.Context, orgName string) ([]*UserDetails, error) {
    var userDetails []*UserDetails
    q := datastore.NewQuery(userDetailsKind).
        Namespace(orgName)
    keys, err := c.client.GetAll(ctx, q, &userDetails)
    for i, key := range keys {
        userDetails[i].NameID = key.Name
    }
    return userDetails, err
}
```

How can i read `UserType` from datastore using above code into `UserDetails.UserType` enum?

Comment: The code should work as written. What problem did you encounter?

Comment: I am trying to understand how `userRole` from datastore, will be mapped to `UserType`? Unfortunately, i don't have anything setup locally and only option is to run in prod which i can't do.

Comment: The datastore package encodes and decodes types with [kind string](https://godoc.org/reflect#Kind.String) as datastore strings.   The underlying string value is transferred do and from the datastore with no translation.

Comment: Run https://play.golang.org/p/MRN-jKt-HrI to observe how the datastore codec handles fields with type `UserType` .

Comment: So I can just test datastore on golang playground. Nice. This is what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question works as is. There's no need to implement PropertyLoadSaver or loop over returned entities as suggested in other answers.

The custom data type is a string. The datastore package marshals all string types to and from datastore strings.  It just works.

Answer (score 0):

What you're essentially doing with UserType is that you have two valid values, and you're mapping all other values to a common unknown value. The following should work:

```
for i, key := range keys {
        userDetails[i].NameID = key.Name
        userDetails[i].UserRole = UserTypeFromString( string(userDetails[i].UserRole))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make your struct implement PropertyLoadSaver interface

https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#hdr-The_PropertyLoadSaver_Interface

then you can handle these special requirements. You wouldn't have to remember to post process with every get/query.